# golang gookit validate does not work with global custom validator

Tags: go

I am trying to use golang gookit validator and adding custom validator, but the function never got fired.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gookit/validate"
)

type Sample struct {
    Name    string `json:"name" validate:"required"`
    Addres  string `json:"address" validate:"required"`
    Payment string `json:"payment" validate:"payment_method"`
}

func main() {
    validate.AddValidator("payment_method", func(val interface{}) bool {
        value, ok := val.(string)
        fmt.Println(value)
        if !ok {
            return false
        }
        if value != "hello" {
            return false
        }
        return true
    })
    s := Sample{Name: "name", Addres: "address", Payment: ""}
    v := validate.Struct(&s)
    res := v.Validate()
    if !res {
        fmt.Println(v.Errors.OneError())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("SUCCESS")
    }
}
```

The result will be always success and the custom validator never get called. Directly on [go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/IHnbghTviml)

Comment: @Alpin, If the answer is correct, can you please upvote it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly mention in the *config*,

> not to skip empty values

like below:

```
validate.Config(func(opt *validate.GlobalOption) {
        opt.SkipOnEmpty = false
})
```

Then, run the code, it will work